# Autolink a keyword in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need specific keyword in specific page is autolinked to specified url.
Is any wordpress plugin available for this.

But it should be applied for specific page or post alone. not to entire page

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

so many plugins is there autolink page

```
Linkify Text

Autolink URI

WP KeyLink

BioDic Automatic word link

Internal Link Manager

Twitterify

Pages Autolink

Tags Autolink
```

u can visit this page also  https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/autolink

Comment: But it should be applied for specific page alone. not to entire page